# How to specify the array's order returned by pandas's `DataFrame.to_numpy`?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In some case, the `order` (Fortran-contiguous or C-contiguous) of numpy's array is useful.
For example, the `sklearn.linear_model.lass_path` need the `X` value be a Fortran-contiguous to avoid unnecessary memory duplication.

However, the `to_numpy` function in `DataFrame` has no way to specify the order of returned value.

Note: I **do not** want unnecessary data copy for performance.

Comment: Would using nditer and 'F' option be helpful? You could also try transposing it and looping 'C' wise (normal). Let me know your thoughts, happy to have a discussion with you if needed.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to guarantee that pandas returns a F_contiguous array: the [relevant code section](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/9d598a5e1eee26df95b3910e3f2934890d062caa/pandas/core/internals/managers.py#L860-L874) doesn't enforce any particular order (although in most 'regular' cases to array will be F_contiguous as data are organized as a bunch of columns internally). One possible solution would be `np.asfortranarray(df)` but this of course doesn't guarantee that no copy is being made.